# How does Amazon Tier/Instance time works?

Tags: web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get a free tier + cheap medium instance which I was told that I can get cheaply for $5 and I can use it only for 100 hours. Here's what I'm confused about, does that 100 hours counts from the time when the instance start working and responding or where I only use it, for example I use it for 2 hours today and a week later I have 98 hours left to use ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a server, you are "using" it until you shut it down. You are charged for the entire time the server is running (in 1 hour increments). Just because you aren't logged into the server and actively using it is irrelevant in regards to billing. As long as the server exists it is using resources and you will be billed for those resources.

Comment: So I only get my time limit gotten away when the server is turned on right ? Then I should be able to turn it off via SSH ?

Comment: You can stop the server, at which point you will only be paying for storage resources. You can stop and start the server via the AWS console or the AWS CLI. You can stop via ssh, but not start obviously.

Comment: You should read the documentation instead of coming here and asking people to recite it to you. https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/  http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html